# Set an empty array in state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-state-management, react-state

In my application I have a initial state that start with some values.
In a process, I need to change this state for a empty array, (that is a return of my Api).

I am trying do this, but the value of the state don't change.

What can I do?

My code

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import "./style.scss";
import Services from "../../services/Services";

export default function Acoplamento({history, match}) {

    const [veiculos, setVeiculos] = useState([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [type, setType] = useState(1);

    const getAllVeiculos = async () => {
        setLoading(true);
        await Services.VeiculoServices.getAll().then(result => {
            setVeiculos(result.data); // Here, i have a array with some objects
        }).catch(error => {
            error(error.message);
        }).finally(() => setLoading(false));
        return true;
    }

    const getOneVeiculos = async () => {
        setLoading(true);
        await Services.VeiculoServices.get().then(result => {
            setVeiculos(result.data); // Here, my return is a empty array, but my state don't chage
        }).catch(error => {
            error(error.message);
        }).finally(() => setLoading(false));
        return true;
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if (type === 1) {
            getAllVeiculos();
        }
        if (type === 2) {
            getOneVeiculos();
        }
    }, [type]);

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={() => setType(2)}>Click</button>
            {veiculos.map(item => (
                <div>{item.name}</div>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: the piece of code that you gave isn't the source of your code unexpected behavior, without any other context it's impossible to help you

Comment: where are you logging state

Comment: @HagaiHarari, I edited the question and put all code.

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I put in code.

Comment: Where and how exactly did you log your state and saying it not updated?

Comment: @TonyNguyen the state that don't change is the veiculos.

When my application starts, the veiculos received a array from my apiand this data is put in the state.  In a secund moment, a other requisition is did and your value returned is a empty array. I need to put this value in my state veiculos, but when I do this, the state don't change and, the last values continue in screen.

Comment: There is many reason that stop the state getting updated. You might want to add log in your code to see what you get it each step. E.g you want to log you `result` and `error` from `Services.VeiculoServices.get()` to see what you get because it might be failed when calling that api. Or create a `useEffect` with dependencies `[veiculos]` and add `console.log` in the to log the `veiculos` whenever it changes

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem arises because you did not convert the incoming data to json format. It can solve the following code problem.

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import "./style.scss";
import Services from "../../services/Services";

export default function Acoplamento({history, match}) {

    const [veiculos, setVeiculos] = useState([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [type, setType] = useState(1);

    const getAllVeiculos = async () => {
        setLoading(true);
        const response = await Services.VeiculoServices.getAll();
        const result = await response.json();
        if (result.data) setVeiculos(result.data);
        setLoading(false);
    }

    const getOneVeiculos = async () => {
        setLoading(true);
        const response = await Services.VeiculoServices.get();
        const result = await response.json();
        if (result.data) setVeiculos(result.data);
        setLoading(false);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if (type === 1) {
            getAllVeiculos();
        }else if (type === 2) {
            getOneVeiculos();
        }
    }, [type]);

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={() => setType(2)}>Click</button>
            {veiculos.map(item => (
                <div>{item.name}</div>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}
```